# How to set volume in decibels using my android mobile application?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am working on a mobile app, where i need to play the sound file. On volume button press, i need to increase/decrease the volume through my app.
I am using Media player to play and using SetVolume(left, right) function to set the volume.

```
MediaPlayer mp;
float left = 0.0f;
float right = 0.6f;

public void OnPlay(View v){ 
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.twofiftybeep);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    mp.start();


    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // Playing the file continuously
            mp.setVolume(left, right);

            mp.start();

        }
    } );
}

public void OnStop(View v){
    mp.stop();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        left= left + 0.05f;
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        left = left - 0.05f;
        return true;
    default:
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

}
```

But SetVolume parameters ranges from 0.0f to 1.0f where 0.0f is for minimum and 1.0f is for maximum.

But i want to set some thing like 40dB, 50dB, 60dB etc.
On every volume button press, i want to either increment or decrement 5dB.

How can i make the 0.0f - 1.0f range to dB value conversion?

Is there any other best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For digital signal dB is typically expressed relative to the full scale amplitude.

```
1.0 == 0dB
0.5 == -6dB
0.25 == -12dB
...
0.0  == -inf dB
```

and so on.

To convert the amplitude to dB:  `dB = 20*log10(ampl)`

To convert from dB to amplitude: `ampl = 10 ^ (dB/20)`

The simplest way to then achieve your goal is to store your values `left` and `right` in dB, initializing them both to zero. Your posted code can stay exactly the same except you wouldn't allow the values to be incremented above zero. Then convert the values to linear as you are calling `setVolume`. e.g. `mp.setVolume(Math.pow(10,left/20), Math.pow(10,right/20))`

Comment: Hi Jaket, i am bit confused with these conversion. How come 1.0 will be 0dB in conversion. Because if i set a volume of (1.0f, 1.0f) i could hear some sound from mobile which can never be a 0dB. For example Samsung S3 phone gives maximum sound of 81dB. As per the API description MediaPlayer.SetVolume(1.0f, 1.0f) gives maximum volume by the mobile phone. That may vary with mobile to mobile depending upon the mobile hardware design. So If use this API in Samsung S3 phone, i should get ~81dB or close to that. I am still confused with  above mathematical conversion. Excuse if i miss some basics.

Comment: dB is always relative to something. In digital it is relative to the full scale amplitude which is 1.0 (20*log10(1)==0). As far as the output of the speaker on a mobile phone, you will need to know the gain in order to convert. If, as you say, the S3 has a max output of 81dB (dBSPL I presume) at full scale (0 dBFS) then you can simply take add 81 - so -5dBFS == +76dBSPL

Comment: Hi @jaket, I want to play sounds using loudness in dB specified in [speech banana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_banana#/media/File:Speech_Banana_no_icons.png) which they are positive numbers from 0 to 120 dB but your calculation here ranges from 0 to -inf dB. So I'm confusing that how can I play a sound with 40 dB, according to calculation here I would got `ampl = 10 ^ (40/20) = 100` which is over 1.0. Sorry if I miss some basics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't set an absolute decibel rating programatically.  Such a concept doesn't actually exist with audio.  That would require knowing the physical configuration the speakers, room acoustings, how close to the user's ear, and measuring the samples from the sound file.

MediaPlayer.setVolume sets attenuation - not loudness or volume.

The volume specified by `MediaPlayer.setVolume` is relative to the hardware volume setting. You can't make the media source "louder" than it really is without adjusting the device volume. And with the MediaPlayer by itself, you don't really know how "loud" the user is hearing anything.

At the highest setting:  `player.setvolume(1.0, 1.0)` - This will set the volume on the output stream to match the global volume on the device.  This is the default.

And as you might have guessed - `player.setvolume(0.0, 0.0)` - is absolute silence.

If you want to set global volume, you can use [AudioManager.setStreamVolume](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int))

Considering that the device and Android volume buttons work perfectly well without the developer having to handle the button presses, I'm not sure why you would want to override default behavior.

Comment: Hi selbie, thank you very much for your post. It answers my question. My mobile app should tell the user at what dB the user is operating. Its the requirement. So i have to look for the alternative by reading the raw data of sound file and vary the volume readings.