# Control Android Brightness and Volume at Set Time

Tags: android, volume, brightness

I am trying to create an Android app that will change the volume and brightness of the user's device at a time either set by the user, or hard coded into the app itself.

I have searched on StackOverflow, but the closest I have got to is setting the brightness only in the app. I want the app to set the brightness and volume permanently across the entire device until the set time passes. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the methods that you are looking for on the android developer documentation.

Setting Volume:
The AdjustVolume(int,int) method should be what you are looking for.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#adjustVolume(int,%20int)

Settings Brightness:

```
private void setBrightness(int brightness) {
    try {
      IHardwareService hardware = IHardwareService.Stub.asInterface(
ServiceManager.getService("hardware"));
      if (hardware != null) {
        hardware.setScreenBacklight(brightness);
      }
    } catch (RemoteException doe) {          
    }        
  }
```

https://web.archive.org/web/20210224163252/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/changing-screen-brightness.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question. It looks similar to your problem

[How to set volume in decibels using my android mobile application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604452/how-to-set-volume-in-decibels-using-my-android-mobile-application/25604990#25604990)

In the above mentioned question he has a media player object and he uses that to change the volume. The code to do that is -

```
public void OnPlay(View v){ 

mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.twofiftybeep);
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

mp.start();


mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // Playing the file continuously
        mp.setVolume(left, right);

        mp.start();

    }
} );
}
```